# Strong Markov Property Clarification

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

I see that there have been many questions on the strong Markov property, including [Strong Markov property - Durrett](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127764/strong-markov-property-durrett) and [Two definitions of the strong Markov property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052383/two-definitions-of-the-strong-markov-property).

I am still slightly confused about one item:

From my understanding of the strong Markov property, if $T$ is a stopping time, $X_n$ is a Markov chain (say on a finite state space $\mathcal{S}$), and $\mu$ denotes the initial distribution of $X_0$ then Durrett says (for example)
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}_{\mu}(X_{T+1}|\mathcal{F}_T) = \mathbb{E}(X_{T+1}|X_T) \quad \text{on } \{T < \infty\}.
\end{equation}
My question is: On the left-hand side, if we are conditioning on the stopping time $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}_T$, we already 'know' all the information  up to the stopping time $T$ (in particular, information about the value taken by $X_0$). So shouldn't in this situation
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}_{\mu}(X_{T+1}|\mathcal{F}_T) = \mathbb{E}(X_{T+1}|\mathcal{F}_T)?
\end{equation}
If so, I suppose that this equality cannot hold in general, otherwise authors would have not bothered to include the subscript $\mu$. Why?
(If I can improve the question clarity please let me know.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look very carefully at equations (1) and (2) [in this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052383/two-definitions-of-the-strong-markov-property)
 The right hand side of (1) is *not* a conditional expectation, and does not depend on the initial  distribution.

On the other hand, your equation 
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}_{\mu}(X_{T+1}|\mathcal{F}_T) = \mathbb{E}(X_{T+1}|X_T) \quad \text{on } \{T < \infty\}.
\tag{incorrect}\end{equation}
has conditional expectations on both sides, and should be written
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}_{\mu}(X_{T+1}|\mathcal{F}_T) = \mathbb{E}_{\mu}(X_{T+1}|X_T) \quad \text{on } \{T < \infty\},\tag{correct}
\end{equation}
as you thought.